# What's going wrong with my render?

Tags: rendering

(This is a re-upload with a link to the file)
I have a scene that is pretty much ready for render, and in the render mode of the viewport it looks good. But whenever I try to render it, materials change and the lighting goes wonky. I can't see any reason why this would happen. I'm using the current version of blender.

File: [image]

Comment: maybe you see something different, but this is what i see in your rendered view and after rendering.... [![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zK73.jpg ...is this ok or....?

Comment: I just get a blank screen. So there must be something wrong with my computer.

Comment: Maybe restart?

Comment: Hello, please post screenshots and add more details so we don't have to download random files. Also using a title that clearly reflects the problems helps user pinpoint your actual problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)